# Angularfire 2 cannot view image after saving it to storage

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, angular5, angularfire2

I am using Angular 5 and trying to upload an avatar for users to Firebase storage and then get the download url for the image to display it and save the url to their profile.

I can upload the image ok with the following code:

```
uploadFile() {

// // The storage path
const path = `profile_images/${this.profile.user_id}`;

// // Totally optional metadata
const customMetadata = { app: 'Some extra data' };

// The main task
this.task = this.storage.upload(path, file, { customMetadata })

// Progress monitoring
this.percentage = this.task.percentageChanges();
this.snapshot = this.task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
  tap(snap => {
    if (snap.bytesTransferred === snap.totalBytes) {

      // Never gets called *************
      console.log('store the path');

    }
  })
)

this.downloadURL = this.task.downloadURL(); 

}
```

If I go into firebase console i can see the image and if i copy the downloadUrl to my clipboard and paste it into a browser i can see the image.  Then I try to get the url needed to view the stored image with the following code:

```
const storageRef = this.storage.ref(path).getDownloadURL().subscribe(url => 
{
  console.log('url', url);

  this.db.collection('photos').add( { url });

  // This url generates the error
  this.profile.image_url = url;

  this.downloadURL = url;

} );
```

The problem is the url returned here generates this error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Permission denied. Could not perform this operation"
  }
}
```

My security rules for storage are:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth!=null;
    }
  }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, been on this problem for days

Thanks
PK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned, your code is not storing the path in Firestore, I have changed following lines inside 'uploadFile()' function and it worked:

```
// * * *
// Progress monitoring
this.percentage = this.task.percentageChanges();
this.snapshot = this.task.snapshotChanges();
// don't need this ^, but I still kept it
// then changed following lines
this.task.snapshotChanges().subscribe(snap => {
    if (snap.bytesTransferred === snap.totalBytes) {
       // Update firestore on completion
       this.db.collection('photos').add( { path, size: snap.totalBytes });
    }
});
```